# Nested grids in Extjs 4

Tags: datagrid, extjs, extjs4

I need to implement a nested grid functionality in extjs 4. I searched online and it seems like Rowexpander from http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2/examples/grid/grid-plugins.html  is the way to go. My issue is that I can't get it to work to display another grid (displaying text works fine).

I need to make it look like this: http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/RowExpander/MultiLevel_GridPanel/ using pure extjs 4.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ext3 I used the rowexpander and embedded a grid, but later discovered odd IE issues when further enhancing it with things like rowactions, pagination, scrolling on the nested grid, etc.  It also adds visual complexity vs a layout where you have 1 grid above another grid.  You click a row in the upper grid and it loads the lower grid for the "nested" data related to that row.  Obviously that pattern only works for a single nesting.  If you need it nested further, you really want a tree and I would use this:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2/examples/tree/treegrid.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into connecting two grids instead of doing nested ones.  Re treegrid - I don't think that's going to work for me. I am not trying to group grid items, but rather display one-to-many.

Comment: Ok cool, this is an example of the rowselectionmodel where you'd change out the data template section below for another grid:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/binding-with-classes.html